# C# COM interop via MethodInfo.Invoke: int* parameters?

Tags: c#, com, interop

Suppose I have a COM object that I've instantiated via Activator.CreateInstance:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myGuid);
```

Now, I know this object has a function that accepts an int* as an argument:

```
virtual void Method(int * outParameter) = 0;
```

This method simply writes a single integer to outParameter. In C++, I would do this:

```
int parameter = 0;
obj->Method(&parameter);
// parameter now contains the result.
```

How do I do the equivalent in C# via MethodInfo.Invoke?

```
MethodInfo method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("Method", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
method.Invoke(obj, ???); // What do I put here?
```

Comment: Open your COM DLL with OleView and show us the exact signature of your `Method`, as defined in IDL. I expect it to look like `HRESULT Method([out] int* p)` for my answer to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, that's not a COM compatible function signature.  It *must* return an HRESULT to be compatible, you'd have to declare the interface yourself with a [PreserveSig] on the method so the CLR knows not to check the return value and throw an exception.  It is also missing the required __stdcall attribute (aka STDMETHOD), another COM requirement.

Your only hope is that you got the C++ declaration wrong.  Quickest way to check is to use the *dynamic* keyword:

```
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myGuid);
int parameter;
obj.Method(out parameter);
```

Or, since it actually looks a lot like a property getter:

```
int parameter = obj.Method();
```

But with the expectation that it will randomly throw an exception and/or imbalance the stack.  Thoroughly testing is required to ensure that the random return value won't trip the exception.

That's a lot of guessing however, best not to do this, especially if you are sure about the signature.  Write a C++/CLI wrapper instead.

Comment: It appears that the object I'm trying to work with is not a proper COM object (probably why I cannot instantiate it directly in the first place...) I'm now working on a C++/CLI wrapper, though I was trying to avoid that!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an array of `int` with a single element in `parameters` for `method.Invoke`:

```
var byrefArg = new int[1];
method.Invoke(obj, .... , new Object[] { byrefArg }, ...);
var outParameter = byrefArg[0];
```